# Implement a login system only via email in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a `User` model and `Admin` model implemented through Devise.

I would like the `Admin` model to send emails with sign up links for the regular users; the regular users should not be able to sign up otherwise.

As of now, I have `Admin` set as `:registerable`, and `User` not set as `:registerable`. How would I send out an email with a signup link for the user?

Answer (score 1):

use device invitable  . https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable . Easy solution.

Comment: how would I implement the registration though? Because I don't want the user to register otherwise. Making it :registerable would open up the links for signup, but also expose them.